# Access the row number in lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I would like to access the current row number in a lapply-iteration:

```
lapply(dplyr::starwars$name[1:3], function(x){
  lapply(dplyr::starwars$name[2:4], function(y){
    paste(x,'&',y)
  })
})
```

In the second lapply-statement I need to access the following entry of the current first one, so instead of this output

```
x[1] - y[2]     Luke Skywalker & C-3PO
x[1] - y[3]     Luke Skywalker & R2-D2
x[1] - y[4]     Luke Skywalker & Darth Vader

x[2] - y[2]     C-3PO & C-3PO
x[2] - y[3]     C-3PO & R2-D2
x[2] - y[4]     C-3PO & Darth Vader

x[3] - y[2]     R2-D2 & C-3PO
x[3] - y[3]     R2-D2 & R2-D2
x[3] - y[4]     R2-D2 & Darth Vader
```

I would like to have this output to avoid getting the same row twice

```
x[1] - y[2]     Luke Skywalker & C-3PO
x[1] - y[3]     Luke Skywalker & R2-D2
x[1] - y[4]     Luke Skywalker & Darth Vader

x[2] - y[3]     C-3PO & R2-D2
x[2] - y[4]     C-3PO & Darth Vader

x[3] - y[4]     R2-D2 & Darth Vader
```

Is it possible to get the current row number (first lapply) back and put it into the second lapply?

Answer (score 1):

How about a different approach:

```
combn(starwars$name[1:4], 2, paste, collapse = " & ")

[1] "Luke Skywalker & C-3PO"       "Luke Skywalker & R2-D2"       "Luke Skywalker & Darth Vader" "C-3PO & R2-D2"                "C-3PO & Darth Vader"         
[6] "R2-D2 & Darth Vader"
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to do it with lapply, I actually want to compare huge data sets with parLapply

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use `lapply` on the indices, but refer to the data inside the function

```
lapply(1:3, function(x){
    lapply((x+1):4, function(y){
        paste(dplyr::starwars$name[x],'&',dplyr::starwars$name[y])
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that should save a lot of calculating time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
result<-lapply(dplyr::starwars$name[1:3], function(x){
  lapply(dplyr::starwars$name[2:4], function(y){
if(x!=y) paste(x,'&',y) else NULL
  })
})
unlist(result)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's 7 results instead of 6 ("C-3PO & R2-D2" & "R2-D2 & C-3PO") and it doesn't seem to be so efficient because of the NULL entries